# How to match single occurrence of a character after a specific word?

Tags: regex

So I have something like:
*Hi my name is Jack*

and I want to match the single space after the word 'name' but not 'is'
I tried `\s{1}(?!name)` but it still matches all spaces after the word name.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: So use `(?<=name)\s`

Comment: Can't you use a capture group for this? If your regex is `name(\s)` then the first capture group will be the single space after "name".

Answer (score 0):

Using a lookbehind such as: `(?<=name)\s` would work just fine.

If you wish to use a lookahead you could lookahead to 'is' and use a positive lookahead i.e. `\s{1}(?=is)` which looks for the whitespace which is immediately followed by the word is. In this case it would work but in a more complex case this would match every occurrence of this, which is likely not the result you are looking for.

In your example you are looking a single occurrence of a whitespace which is **not** followed by name. If you use a tool like regex101 you will find that you are matching all single occurrences of a blank space bar that one. If you use `\s{1}(?!Jack)` you will get all occurrences **except** the whitespace before the word Jack. That is why your example does not work.